# Unable to Parse String from LogCat Inside Service

Tags: java, android, string

So I have a string like this (got it from LogCat) that I receive as from the function below:

```
private OriginalPermissions identifyPermission(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    List < AccessibilityNodeInfo > mFoundNodeInfos;
    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
    for (Map.Entry < OriginalPermissions, String > permissions: pePers.entrySet()) {
        mFoundNodeInfos = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(permissions.getValue());

        //Get Application Information
        Log.d("Information", appNamer(String.valueOf(mFoundNodeInfos)));

        if (mFoundNodeInfos.size() == 1) return permissions.getKey();
    }
    return OriginalPermissions.OTHER;
}
```

Now, this is the string returned:

```
[android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@800290aa; boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 566, 195); boundsInScreen: Rect(310, 691 - 876, 886); packageName: com.google.android.packageinstaller; className: android.widget.TextView; text: Allow Camera to take pictures and record video?; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_message; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN - null]]
```

Now I have to get the string between the 2 words `Allow` and `to`. What I tried is this:

```
private String appNamer(String parse){
     parse = parse.substring(parse.indexOf("Allow") + 6 , parse.length());
     parse = parse.substring(0, parse.indexOf(' '));
     return parse;
}
```

This code works perfectly on an individual basis, but when running inside my android app as given below, I immediately get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception`.

```
Log.d("Information", appNamer(appNamer(String.valueOf(mFoundNodeInfos))));
```

This is the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers, PID: 31783
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; regionStart=5; regionLength=-3
   at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
   at com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers.PePersDetectorService.appNamer(PePersDetectorService.java:253)
   at com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers.PePersDetectorService.identifyPermission(PePersDetectorService.java:243)
   at com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers.PePersDetectorService.handlePermissionRequest(PePersDetectorService.java:80)
   at com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers.PePersDetectorService.access$300(PePersDetectorService.java:29)
   at com.triple.m.crabzilla.pepers.PePersDetectorService$AccessibilityEventProcessor$1.run(PePersDetectorService.java:134)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Without  the string parsing logic, the `Log` works perfectly! Where have I done wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try to print your string before parsing it. It may not be what you think it is.

Comment: Perfect! Please write this as an answer for me to mark. I just had to make sure the string length is large enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. As asked I'll write this as an answer.

Print your string just before you're parsing it. It may not be what you think it is.

Generally speaking, dont assume a variable's value and abuse of the `print` function and of the debugging mode. This will tell you what is actually happening in your program, and prevent you to look for the wrong mistake.